# XMonad "toggle" keybind

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Hi I'm completely new to XMonad and haskell and I'm having an hard time defining custom function for a keybind.

I'm using `XMonad.Actions.TagWindows` and I'm trying to define a function that brings windows with a specific tag in the current workspace or send the focused window in a designated workspace if it's tagged.
Right now I've achieved this behaviour using two different keybindings.

```hs
    , ((0,   xK_KP_Home  ), withTaggedGlobalP "Editor" shiftHere)
    , ((altKPMask,   xK_KP_Home  ), withTaggedP "Editor" (W.shiftWin "Editor"))
```

This does roughly what I want but I'd like to have a single keybind for it so I tried to define function that checks the tag of the focused window and behaves accordingly and this is what I came up with:

```hs
    tagFunc tag w = 
         if hasTag tag w 
         then W.shiftWin tag w 
         else  withTaggedGlobal tag shiftHere
```

But I got an error stating

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool` with actual type `X Bool`
```

And I don't know how to solve it, I've searched for a way to convert X Bool to Bool with no luck.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don’t know XMonad, but it seems like your problem is that `hasTag` returns a value of type `X Bool`. This presumably is the titular `X` monad. I won’t explain the gory details of how things work since I figure you just want your configuration to compile. One way to deal with monads is to use `do` notation. I indicate newlines with `\n` and I don’t indent: `tagFunc tag w = do \n result <- hasTag tag w \n if result \n then -- then case \n else -- else case`. Essentially, we have to “extract” the `Bool` from `X Bool`. Hope this helps.